# how to change class name of div tag dynamically which is in curly braces using javascript in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I need to know how to change the class name of div tag dynamically which is in curly braces using javascript in django.Normally we did with the help of attr. Here i am little confused to change it.The div tag look like below

```
 <div class="clname{{progress}}"></div>
```

I need to change the value of **progress** which is mentioned the above div tag.Anyone know about to change it using javascript. please let me know how to do that.

progress value should be change dynamically as 0,1,2,3,etc....

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Django will only set the `{{progress}}` value when the template is rendered. Your question is a bit unclear -- can you clarify what you are trying to do? Do you have multiple `<div>` elements on the page and want them numbered sequentially down the page? Are you trying to show a progress div as Django processes something on the server? You need to clarify your use case if you want a better solution...

Answer (score 0):

it's Very Simple using jquery.

```
$("div").replace("{{progress}}", "replaceValue");
```

Answer (score 0):

We can replace it with new class.
I following class we are replacing two class with class name .greenBackground.

```js
window.onload=function(){
   document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",function(){
    document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].className = "greenBackground";
   });
  };
```

```css
.redBackround
  {
   height:200px;
   width:200px;
   background: red;
  }
  .greenBackground
  {
   height:200px;
   width:200px;
   background: green;
  }
```

```html
<div class="redBackround extraClass"> </div>
 <button id="btn">click</button>
```

Comment: thanks for your response. but i didn't ask about to change the first class name.. am asking about to change {{progress}} value which is mentioned above. how to change it dynamically using javascript.I am working in django

Comment: i dont have deep knowledge of django, but if we assign new classname to div using .className property all classes with div has been overwritten.

Comment: You can directly change value of class using above code. Try it